# pip cannot find package from local pypi (jfrog artifactory)

Tags: python, pip, artifactory, pypi

We have a local pypi in which we put some python packages. However, pip is unable to install the package.

pip search will find the package:

```
$ pip search --index=http://artifactory.ours.com/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple hello        
hello     - UNKNOWN
```

But pip install gives the following:

```
pip install --pre -r requirements.txt --trusted-host=artifactory.ours.com
```

> Collecting hello (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))   Could not
>   find a version that satisfies the requirement hello (from -r
>   requirements.txt (line 4)) (from versions: ) No matching distribution
>   found for hello (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))

and here is the requirements.txt:

```
# requirements.txt
--allow-all-external
--extra-index-url http://artifactory.ours.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple

hello
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem seems to be lifted if I use an older version of pip like `1.x`. Not sure if this is jfrog bug or related to pip itself.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that your package does not have a version number.  Your setup.py does not specify the version.

Example from the Python documents (the example is for distutils):

https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html

Comment: Thanks but the package has `0.0.1` version in `setup.py`.

Answer (score -1):

Another possible cause for this issue is when you use hyphen(-) in the name of the package while uploading it to artifactory. pip can successfully search and find your package but it cannot install it. Replace the hyphen with underscore.